# Can I get the username of the logged in user as a Paw dynamic value?

Tags: paw-app

I'm working with a team of people who are using Paw, the API tool for macOS, to develop and test an API that we are building. It would be very helpful to include the name of the user along with each request, so that we can distinguish between requests from different people in the logs.

Does Paw have any way of getting the current username as a Dynamic Value? Any of these solutions would be great.

- A dynamic value that retrieves environment variables so that I could use the `$USER` environment variable.
- A dynamic value that executes a shell command so that I could get a directory name or environment variable or some other indicator.
- A dynamic value that expresses the User ID or email address of the user currently signed in to Paw Cloud.

Comment: Paw extensions can't see environment variables from within their JavaScript sandbox. :(

Comment: Unfortunately, Paw doesn't let the JavaScript context access the username or email address of the logged-in user. Though, you may access environment variables declared in Paw's UI through: context.​getEnvironmentVariableByName(variableName).getCurrentValue(). See https://paw.cloud/docs/reference/ExtensionContext.

Comment: @MichaMazaheri could you add that as an answer to the question?